# how to port forward to one device while another device shared the same public ip

Tags: networking, ip, port, router, portforwarding

my ISP only gave me one public ip address, i want to port forward on a single device but all the devices connected to the router shared the same public ip address.

is there a way to do it?

i use hg8245h  router

i tried to open a port as below image

[image: image1]

but it's not opened when i check [image: image2]

Comment: Use different port for every local IP behind the router.

Comment: @DamianK , i want to open port for only one computer, and that what i did in the router setting , but everytime i check it's closed, i think because all my devices that is connected to the router have the same public ip.

Comment: just one thing to keep in mind, your ISP might be blocking some ports on their side for consumer-grade connections (you could probably also check with them how to set up port forwarding for your specific router model while you're at it)

Comment: This question is off topic.

Comment: You should confirm first with your ISP provider that you really have public IP from them.
Just because you can see your public IP on various websites does not mean that it is assigned only to your router

Answer (score 0):

What you have setup looks good as far as port forwarding goes.

Make sure to open the port in the firewall settings as well, you have firewall settings both on the router, and the computer (NewKali).

Make sure you can connect from one of the other computers on the network to 192.168.100.32:4444 to confirm the pc has the firewall open.

To confirm the router firewall settings look at the appropriate configuration page.